# How to export multi page pdf into multi page JPEG in preview?

Tags: pdf, preview, image-editing

I have a pdf document with 5 pages. I would like to export it in JPEG format (or any image format). But if I hit File->export->export as JPEG, it only saves the first page of the pdf document as a JPEG image. Is it possible to export all of the pages to JPEG format?

Answer (score 1):

Use macOS Automator to perform a [multi-page PDF export into multiple JPG images](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3311405):

[image: Automator Action on macOS]

I faced the same challenge. Obviously, macOS Preview will only export one page from the PDF at a time to a JPG image.

I tested the above solution and it worked fine.